# Using Launchpad with folders

Tags: macos, launchpad

Prior to Lion I used [overflow](http://stuntsoftware.com/overflow/) as a program launcher.  I'm trying to replace that with Launchpad (one less app to deal with) and it seems to be working...almost.

Is there any way I can add an icon in Launchpad that opens a folder or a specific file (pdf for example)?  I've got all my application icons in place, I'm just trying to get the last few shortcuts from overflow into Launchpad.

Comment: To my dismay - some PDF that were bundled with Microsoft Office seem to show up in Launchbar as an app - finder even shows them as app - so apparently it's possible even though I really like the distinction between apps and docs to remain far apart. Maybe someone can tear those files apart and get you a wrapper for the files you want launch able?

Comment: Odd, I installed Office 2011 and didn't get any of that - I did do a custom install so maybe I missed that as a part of my install...?

Comment: /Applicaions/Microsoft Expression Media/Expression Media.app is one offender. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I got a little trick that will do that, with Automator. Launch Automator and create an an Application workflow. Add the following actions:
"Get Specified Finder Items" -> here's where you specify the folder you want opened.
"Open Finder Items"

[image]

Then save the workflow and drag it to Launchpad. You might wanna change the icon too. Works just like a folder.

Comment: It seems like a lot of extra work but that did the trick for me for both Folders and for files (pdfs, etc)